# does Mesos provide its service like cluster management UI as OSS project?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I loved DCOS demos on Azure. No I wonder - having a private OpenStack based clud how to install Mesos with that UI manually? Is it possible or it is a part of DCOS they do not provide as OpenSource product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DCOS Dashboard is pretty cool :-). Currently it is just available via the DCOS beta on AWS and Azure. There will be on prem packages later on as well, potentially even a community edition. Feel free to contact/follow [Mesosphere](https://mesosphere.com/contact/) for updates.

Until then you can use the standard Mesos, Marathon, and Chronos UIs as Alex pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mesos and Marathon WebUI, by default they are available on ports 5050 and 8080 respectively.